# Docker overlay DNS cant resolve Container Name

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm

I have 2 Docker Hosts with identical Docker Version and Configs.
Since yesterday i have a Problem with the Overlay Networks on one of the Hosts. 
What i did:

`docker network create -d overlay --attachable test_network
docker run --rm -it --network="test_network" --name test.DNS.name bash
wget test.DNS.name`

On One Host the response is as expected:

`bash-4.4# wget test.DNS.name
Connecting to test.DNS.name (10.0.1.6:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.1.6): Connection refused`

On the other the response is:

`bash-4.4# wget test.DNS.name
wget: bad address 'test.DNS.name'`

I have no idea where this could come from.

Every Idea is welcome

There the output from docker info (identical on both machines):

`Containers: 3
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 156
Server Version: 18.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: vg01-docker--pool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Data Space Used: 22.89GB
 Data Space Total: 42.95GB
 Data Space Available: 20.06GB
 Metadata Space Used: 6.922MB
 Metadata Space Total: 5.583GB
 Metadata Space Available: 5.576GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 4.295GB
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: m99xj3rhtk8ymabv1k78v4pur
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: of2g9dy3xbwj2jye6potfq5dq
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.16.21.145
 Manager Addresses:
  10.16.21.145:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfd04396dc68220d1cecbe686a6cc3aa5ce3667c
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 62.74GiB
Name: gtunxlvd04346
ID: QPYZ:ZYLJ:DNXO:VCRC:Y2CG:LOEN:WSKN:52X5:JPNX:FLSB:GPIR:FY3U
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false`

Comment: restart docker on that node; if it doesn't work then try to restart the node.

Comment: thangs i will try that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

thanks Constantin for your suggestion, we restartet the Host with the Problem and now it is working as expected.

So this Problem can be solved with a restart of the Host.

It would still be interesting to find the cause of this, but i think that if there is no relation between researching this issue and the chance this happens again.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19769383)

Comment: @DennisC And where is that other answer they are supposed to accept?